# How to serve google cloud storage image from local server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

With the latest GAE SDK (1.9.17), I followed all the instructions for serving google cloud storage images using the blobstore and images libraries, yet locally it gives me a 500 error. Deploying the app to the production server, serving the images works fine. However, this is extremely annoying because I need to develop locally, and my project is image intensive.

This works fine in production:

```
key = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/my_bucket/my_folder/my_image.jpg')
url = images.get_serving_url(key)
```

On production, the serving url looks like:

```
http://lh6.ggpht.com/ow6Z3PrYyLVdvRDc9cT9I3MB9ug...
```

Locally, the url looks like:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:Z2lmdF9p...
```

The App Engine error logs say:

> ERROR    2014-12-21 23:12:35,256 blob_download.py:204] Could not find
>   blob with key
>   encoded_gs_file:Z2lmdF9p...

Am I doing something wrong? The docs say serving images locally should work fine after SDK 1.8. If I can't get this to work, my only solution is to keep all production images (many GB's) hosted locally for development.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

See [this very good repo](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python), which explains how to save file in GCS, either in the development SDK or in production.

Specifically, for your question:

```python
   # image API supported formats
    if file_extension in ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'ico']:
        # High-performance dynamic image serving
        self.serving_url = images.get_serving_url(self.blobkey, secure_url=True)
    elif os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
        # GCS url: this SDK feature has not been documented yet !!!
        self.serving_url = '/_ah/gcs%s' % self.gcs_filename
    else:
        # GCS url: because of HTTPS we cannot use a cname redirect or use the use_blobstore option
        self.serving_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com%s' % self.gcs_filename
```

Thanks to [@voscausa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675006/voscausa).